# Визуальный редактор WPF Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, catel

Есть несоответствие дизайна, который отображается  в визуальном редакторе
и то что компилируется на выходе. Конкретно на скрине отступы от контролов другие. Панель меню (кнопка "Главная") сдвинута от края начала окна.

Существуют ли способы чтобы в визуальном редакторе все выглядело точно также как после компиляции?

(Использую VS 2015,  фреймворк Catel)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под `минимизировать`

Comment: Я имел в виду, чтобы все отступы (скрин 1) между контролами  были аналогичными как на скрин 2.

Comment: Выяснил, что это проблема Catel, но как решить не знаю!

Answer (score 3):

Добавить в пространство имен XAML:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

и далее устанавливайте вашу VM в `d:DataContext`

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance VM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

у VM должен быть конструктор по умолчанию без параметров. В нем задавайте данные которые хотите увидеть в конструкторе.

Comment: Проблему это не решило:(